# AWS CodePipeline stage timeouts / abort?

Tags: jenkins, aws-codepipeline

Is there documentation / detail anywhere about timeouts for stages in CodePipeline? In particular, I have a build stage (Jenkins) which can fail if Jenkins is incorrectly configured, but it doesn't always immediately fail the stage in CodePipeline which is then stuck in "In Progress". It seems to timeout after a long time.

Is there any guidance about how long this timeout takes, or how it can be shortened (e.g. while setting up the pipeline)?
Can a stage be forcefully aborted?
Is there any logging about pipeline runs?

Comment: See amazon forums for a similar problem report: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216350

Comment: Three years later, and there still doesn't seem to be a solution for this beyond deleting the stage and re-creating it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option mentioned in the [CodePipeline docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/codepipeline-user.pdf) (as of this post). AWS included a timeout as

```
"timeoutInMinutes"
```

in CodeBuild (more of an AWS *alternative* to Jenkins).